# How deal with issue in JSF where values are not submitted for fields intially marked as Disabled?

Tags: jsf-2

I have two drop downs on a page whose backing bean is Request Scoped. The second drop down is always disabled when the page is first rendered. However, if the user switches the first drop down to a different value than the default, the second drop down is enabled. When the user submits the form, I want my RequestScoped managed bean to see the value of the second drop down. However, evidently, becuase the second drop down was initially disabled, its value is not submitted with the form, even though when the form was submitted, the dropdown was enabled.

The way I have worked around this is to store the disabled "state" of the second drop down in a ViewScoped bean. That way, when the user changes the first drop down to a value other than the default, an actionListener can fire which will update the value of the ViewScoped bean associated with the second dropdown (changing its state to not disabled).

Is this the best way to deal with this situation? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's indeed the most sane approach.

An alternative, if you *really* need to have your bean in the request scope, is to re-determine the `disabled` state of the second dropdown in the (post)constructor of the bean based on the submitted value of the first dropdown which you can find in the [request parameter map](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterMap%28%29) (or just let JSF set it by `@ManagedProperty`). You only need to manually repeat the JSF conversion/validation if necessary.

Let's assume that the second dropdown should not be disabled anymore when the submitted value of the first dropdown equals the string value `foo` and that the client ID of the first dropdown is `form:dropdown1`:

```
public Bean() {
    this.dropdown2disabled = !"foo".equals(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("form:dropdown1"));
}
```

But as you found out, a view scoped bean is easier.

As again another alternative, you could use [Tomahawk's `<t:saveState>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_saveState.html) to store a single property directly in the view state. Add this somewhere to the view then:

```
<t:saveState value="#{bean.dropdown2disabled}" />
```

This will result in a smaller size of the view state than when using a view scoped bean.

Comment: I thought of using t:saveState, but I wasnt sure Tomahawk would play nice with PrimeFaces. Any idea if it does?

Comment: We have here a live project which uses RichFaces 4, PrimeFaces 3 and Tomahawk 2. No pain as long as we don't mix RichFaces and PrimeFaces in 1 page.

Comment: Good to know, there are some useful things I want to use in Tomahawak 2 (I am on PF 3 as well)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I eventually solved it using a "fake" disabled.

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <p:inputText styleClass="ui-state-disabled">

    <!-- fake-disable input field -->
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;"/>
</div>
```

Using a invisible div above the input the user can't interact with it. Additionally, I styled the input field so that it looks disabled.

Comment: This still allows the enduser/hacker to actually fill, change and submit the value.

Comment: Well, if it's truly a hacker, he can do that anyways. With a bit of jQuery magic, anyone can fill, change and submit a disabled input. So in my opinion there's no difference in disabling the input element and this trick.

Comment: JSF won't process the submitted value if it's in the server side disabled. Apparently you never really used or understood JSF.

Comment: My use case was an input value disabled for the end user but not seen as disabled for the user, so my trick enabled me to submit all data without enabling the field for the user. I'm sorry if I made you think I never used or understood JSF, I hope this clears it up.